# How to implement flat shading in LWJGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm working on a small project in LWJGL. Currently I'm storing vertices, normals, and vertex colors from an obj/mtl file.

I'm trying to prevent vertex shading. That is, I want each polygon to have it's defined color. I've done some reading online and I've seen using the `flat` modifier on shaders, and `gldisable(GL_BLEND)`. So far the only thing that has given me the desired result is creating 6 separate planes and shading them accordingly in Blender.

The sperate planes seems like a total hack, and I don't see how that would scale well.

The cube on the left is simply a cube exported from blender with 6 different materials. The one on the right, what I'm trying to achieve, but its 6 planes modeled to look like a cube, then exported.

[image]

What is the *proper* way to achieve my goal of independently colored faces?

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using inside LWJGL?

Comment: Also, you'd be surprised that your "total hack" is standard practice, particularly when you are mixing flat with smooth shading in a single model.

Comment: @kibibu Version 3.2.0 - How does this scale? Is this something that is configured in the modeling software? Or would I need to parse the polygons into they're "own" object in software?

Comment: Personally I would stick with the "hack" - the only thing the face vertices have in common at the corners is position; the normal and colour attributes are going to be different.

Comment: Bill you can do it during modelling - Blender has a "edge split" modifier that you can use I think.

Comment: Very cool. If you'd like, you can post that as the solution and I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flat` to the output of my vertex shader and `flat` to my fragment shader gave me the desired results

scene_vertex.vs

```
flat out vec3 mvVertexNormal;
flat out vec3 mvVertexPos;
```

scene_fragment.fs

```
flat in vec3 mvVertexNormal;
flat in vec3 mvVertexPos;
```